# Reseting all other jQuery animations except for the current hovered element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a problem with my code. It works normally. But i have 3 boxes next to each other. On hover, They do stuff... ie change width. The problem i have. is that if you move your mouse over all of them they all start. but i just want the one that you stop your mouse on.

So i need to reset all of the other animations when i hover over anyone of these boxes to stop more than one box from being animated at a time. Thanks!

## jquery

```
 function animatedText() {
  var $animatedTextBox = $('.animated-text');
  var $animatedAnimation = $('.animated-text-animation');

  $('.animated-text-content').css('display', 'none');
  $animatedTextBox.on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).find('.animated-text-animation').css('justify-content', 'flex-start');
    $(this).find($('.animated-text-content')).delay(600).fadeIn(800);
  });


  $animatedTextBox.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).find('.animated-text-animation').css('justify-content', 'center');
    $(this).find($('.animated-text-content')).fadeOut(250);
  });
}
```

## css

```
.animated-text {
  min-width: 33.333%;
  min-height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.animated-text-animation {
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 550px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.animated-text:hover .animated-text-animation {
  flex: 1 1 40%;
}

.animated-text:hover {
    min-width: 50%;
}

.animated-text-container:hover .animated-text:not(:hover) {
  min-width: 25%;
}
```

## html

```
  <div class="animated-text-container">
    <div class="animated-text animated-text-1">
      <div class="animated-text-animation">
        <div class="animated-text-logo animated-text-logo-1"></div>
        <div class="animated-text-content">
          <h1>We will do all of the following for free for the first 30 days to prove our ability, our worth, and our character to you:</h1>
          <li><span>Free Positioning Evaluation (Analyzing What you need to succeed)</span></li>
          <li><span>Free Website Evaluation</span></li>
          <li><span>Free Landing Page Evaluation</span></li>
          <li><span>Free (entire) account set-up for a PPC Campaign on AdWords or Bing</span></li>
          <li><span>Free Keyword List Building and Deployment</span></li>
          <li><span>Free Ad Campaign Design and Implementation</span></li>
          <li><span>Free Google Analytics Analysis and Evaluation</span></li>
          <li><span>Free Phone Consultations to Discuss Your Account</span></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="animated-text animated-text-2">
      <div class="animated-text-animation">

        <div class="animated-text-logo animated-text-logo-2"></div>
        <div class="animated-text-content">
          <h1>What we do NOT do for free:</h1>
          <div class="li-container">
            <div class="li-content">
              <li><span>Website Development</span></li>
              <li><span>Landing Page Redesign</span></li>
              <li><span>Local Listing Management</span></li>
              <li><span>Online Reputation Management</span></li>
              <li><span>Audience Remarketing Campaigns</span></li>
            </div>
            <div class="li-content">
              <li><span>Live Chat Services</span></li>
              <li><span>Instant Email Alerts</span></li>
              <li><span>Call Recording & Tracking</span></li>
              <li><span>Website SEO Optimization</span></li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="animated-text animated-text-3">
      <div class="animated-text-animation">

        <div class="animated-text-logo animated-text-logo-3"></div>
        <div class="animated-text-content">
          <h1>It is our earnest goal to:</h1>
          <div class="li-structure">
            <li></li><span>Analyze the current position of your company in the market</span>
          </div>
          <div class="li-structure">
            <li></li><span>Determine what tools and online campaigns you need to increase your sales and customer base</span>
          </div>
          <div class="li-structure">
            <li></li><span>Formulate an effective plan to increase the growth of your company through increased customers</span>
          </div>
          <div class="li-structure">
            <li></li><span>Effectively implement a cost effective advertising campaign to get the most out of every dollar spent</span>
          </div>
          <div class="li-structure">
            <li></li><span>Build an ongoing and long lasting friendship based on mutual trust, respect, and performance</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does your `animatedText()` function is called? From the code you shown, only CSS affects your div's display.

Comment: It is called in prior js. I just didnt add in because of relevance

Answer (score 0):

You could use the stopPropagation method, so that now more than the one you stop your mouse on is triggered. Adjust the delay (500) as needed to the desired effect.

```
var time;
function animatedText() {

  $('.animated-text-content').css('display', 'none');

  $('.animated-text').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    if(time){
        clearTimeout(time);   
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('.animated-text-animation').css('justify-content', 'flex-start');
    $(this).find($('.animated-text-content')).delay(600).fadeIn(800);
  });


  $('.animated-text').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    time = setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
        $(this).find('.animated-text-animation').css('justify-content', 'center');
        $(this).find($('.animated-text-content')).fadeOut(250);
    }, this),500); //Delay   <-------
  });
}
```